# Running an overnight systemd timer on a suspended laptop

Tags: linux, laptop, systemd, suspend

I'd like to schedule a regular overnight backup on a laptop (currently running Ubuntu 20.04), which is normally left suspended.  Systemd timers seem like just the thing, but aren't quite working - the system wakes up at the right time, starts the backup script, and then detects that the lid is closed and goes straight back to sleep.  (The backup continues when the laptop is next brought out of sleep)

I have two systemd files.

`/etc/systemd/system/my_backup.timer`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run backups

[Timer]
OnCalendar=Sat *-*-* 02:00
WakeSystem=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

and `/etc/systemd/system/my_backup.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Run backups

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/root/bin/run_backups.sh
```

I enable it with `systemctl enable my_backup.timer ; systemctl start my_backup.timer`.

And when I try, I get logs looking like below.  The first three lines are before suspending (17:59); I asked it to wake up at 18:02 which it does.  However it then goes straight back to sleep.  I believe this is because systemd detects that the laptop lid is closed; this doesn't happen when the lid is open.

```
Mar 20 17:59:49 redline systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Mar 20 17:59:49 redline systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Mar 20 17:59:49 redline systemd-sleep[1575590]: Suspending system...
Mar 20 18:02:05 redline systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status...
Mar 20 18:02:05 redline systemd[1]: Stopped target Bluetooth.
Mar 20 18:02:05 redline systemd[3277]: Stopped target Bluetooth.
Mar 20 18:02:05 redline systemd[1]: Reached target Bluetooth.
Mar 20 18:02:05 redline systemd[3277]: Reached target Bluetooth.
Mar 20 18:02:05 redline systemd[1]: Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status.
Mar 20 18:02:05 redline systemd-sleep[1575590]: System resumed.
Mar 20 18:02:05 redline systemd-sleep[1575642]: /dev/sda:
Mar 20 18:02:05 redline systemd-sleep[1575642]:  setting Advanced Power Management level to 0xfe (254)
Mar 20 18:02:05 redline systemd-sleep[1575642]:  APM_level        = 254
Mar 20 18:02:06 redline systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Succeeded.
Mar 20 18:02:06 redline systemd[1]: Finished Suspend.
Mar 20 18:02:06 redline systemd[1]: Stopped target Sleep.
Mar 20 18:02:06 redline systemd[1]: Reached target Suspend.
Mar 20 18:02:06 redline systemd[1]: Stopped target Suspend.
Mar 20 18:02:06 redline systemd-logind[1661]: Operation 'sleep' finished.
Mar 20 18:02:10 redline systemd[1]: Starting resolvconf-pull-resolved.service...
Mar 20 18:02:10 redline systemd[1]: resolvconf-pull-resolved.service: Succeeded.
Mar 20 18:02:10 redline systemd[1]: Finished resolvconf-pull-resolved.service.
Mar 20 18:02:10 redline systemd[1]: systemd-rfkill.service: Succeeded.
Mar 20 18:02:20 redline systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
Mar 20 18:02:32 redline systemd-logind[1661]: Suspending...
Mar 20 18:02:32 redline kernel: Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
Mar 20 18:02:32 redline dbus-daemon[1617]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.590275' (uid=0 pid=2807467 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Mar 20 18:02:32 redline kernel: Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
Mar 20 18:02:32 redline systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Mar 20 18:02:32 redline kernel: Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
Mar 20 18:02:32 redline kernel: Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
Mar 20 18:02:32 redline systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Mar 20 18:02:32 redline kernel: Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
Mar 20 18:02:32 redline kernel: Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
Mar 20 18:02:32 redline kernel: Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
Mar 20 18:02:32 redline systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Mar 20 18:02:32 redline systemd[1]: Starting resolvconf-pull-resolved.service...
Mar 20 18:02:32 redline systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
```

I also tried `systemd-inhibit`, but changing the `ExecStart` line to:

```
ExecStart=systemd-inhibit --what=sleep --who=my.backups --why=running.backups --mode=block /root/bin/run_backups.sh
```

This results in an error (which I interpret to be "can't inhibit sleep when we're already entering sleep" but I'm not totally sure).

```
Mar 21 12:13:06 redline systemd-inhibit[1607510]: Failed to inhibit: The operation inhibition has been requested for is already running
Mar 21 12:13:06 redline systemd[1]: my_backup.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 21 12:13:06 redline systemd[1]: my_backup.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I believe this error is the same as described in the (open at time of writing) [systemd issue](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/14045).  The possible workaround in that issue (add a `sleep 1m` before systemd-inhibit to avoid the race) doesn't work for me as it's long gone back into suspend before that happens.

So it looks at first like `WakeSystem=true` combined with `systemd-inhibit` should do exactly what I want, but they don't quite.  But maybe I'm missing something - e.g. better use of systemd targets etc.?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup and use the following timer and service files, hope these help:

`/etc/systemd/system/backup.timer`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Backup

[Timer]
Unit=backup.service
OnCalendar=*-*-* 03:00
WakeSystem=true
Persistent=false

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`/etc/systemd/system/backup.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Backup
RefuseManualStart=true
RefuseManualStop=true
ConditionACPower=true          # ensure power cable plugged in
Wants=network-online.target    # wait for network to be available
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/systemd-inhibit --what=handle-lid-switch --why=backups /bin/su <my_username> -c "/path/to/backup/script"
```

I think the `--what=handle-lid-switch` is the important difference in keeping the system from sleeping right away.

Comment: Thanks, though that didn't seem to help - it still went to sleep again for me.  Maybe it's system specific.